# Why won't opacity change on .mouseleave() event?

Tags: jquery, css, mouseleave

In the following code, the `.mouseover()` portion works fine, but some funny things are happening when `.mouseleave()` portion is trigged.  For one, the opacity of `'.step_details'`is not resetting.  I have tried using both `.animate()` and `.css()` to reset the opacity to 0 with no success.  Any thoughts on why this might be?

```
$('.step').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css({'border': 'solid #CCC 1px', 'background-color': '#FFF'})
        .animate({'margin-top': '0', height: '300px'}, 500);
    $(this).children('.step_details').css('display', 'block')
        .animate({opacity: 1},700); 
})

$('.step').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({'border': 'none', 'background-color': 'inherit'})
        .animate({'margin-top': '150px', height: '150px'}, 200);
    $(this).children('.step_details').css({'display': 'none', 'opacity': 0});
})
```

Also, there is an inconsistent delay between the resetting of the border/background and the start of the animation that resets the top margin and the height of `'.step'`.  This seems to imply that the opacity problem may just be a symptom of me misusing the `.mouseleave()` event trigger.  What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way I should be doing this?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: It would be great, if you can create a minimal [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)/[bin](http://jsbin.com) for it.

Comment: Try. .mouseout() instead

Comment: `.mouseleave()` is fine, .`mouseout()` won't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The opacity won't change because the animation sets `display:none` which is a binary switch to not show that element, any opacity changes won't be seen. However, [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) are a good solution for what you're doing.

[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/wELqx/2/)

```
$('.step').hover(function() { // mouse enter

  $(this).animate({
      'margin-top': '0', 
      height: '300px'
  }, 500).children('.step_details').fadeIn(700);

}, function() { // mouse leave

  $(this).animate({
    'margin-top': '150px', 
    height: '150px'
  }, 200).children('.step_details').fadeOut(200);

});
```

the border/background changes can be handled in the CSS using the `:hover` pseudo-class

```
.step {
  margin-top:150px;
  border:none;
  background-color:#eee;
}
.step:hover {
  border:solid #CCC 1px;
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/DXgr8/1/

You're missing `.stop()`

```
$('.step').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css({border: 'solid #CCC 1px', backgroundColor: '#FFF'})
        .stop().animate({marginTop: '0', height: '300px'}, 500);
    $(this).children('.step_details').stop().animate({opacity: 1},700); 
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css({border: 'none', backgroundColor: 'inherit'})
        .stop().animate({marginTop: '150px', height: '150px'}, 200);
    $(this).children('.step_details').stop().animate({opacity: 0},200);
});
```

NB anyone testing this, the div hides but is still there to hover, just further down than it was